# Updating canvas as soon as value of any HTML element changes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

This is the relevant javascript code

```
<script>
    $.fn.ready(function() {
        var src = $('#src').val();
        Meme('url1', 'canvas','','');
        $('#top-line, #bottom-line').keyup(function() {
            Meme(src, 'canvas', $('#top-line').val(), $('#bottom-line').val());
            if(document.getElementById('stanley').checked) {
                src = 'url2';
                Meme(src, 'canvas', $('#top-line').val(), $('#bottom-line').val());
            } else if(document.getElementById('futurama').checked) {
                src = 'url3';
                Meme(src, 'canvas', $('#top-line').val(), $('#bottom-line').val());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <input type="radio" name="meme" id="stanley" class="input-hidden" />
    <label for="stanley"><img src="url3" alt="" width="80px;" height="80px;"/></label>
    <input type="radio" name="meme" id="futurama" class="input-hidden" />
    <label for="futurama"><img src="url4" alt="" width="80px;" height="80px;" /></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="containcanvas" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <form>
        <input class="form-control" id="src" placeholder="Image URL">
        <input class="form-control" id="top-line" placeholder="top line">
        <input class="form-control" id="bottom-line" placeholder="bottom line">
    </form>
```

For now canvas gets updated if text in top-line and bottom-line changes. To update canvas after a radio button is checked I have put it inside the code where change in value of top and bottom lines updates the canvas. The problem is this method sucks. Another issue is canvas does not get updated after I just enter image url in src. How should I modify this code so that all canvas gets updated as soon as any radio button is checked or any text value in inputs changes?

Comment: So you want the code that currently runs in the `keyup` callback to be run on the radio button `change` event? And on input into the `id="src"` image?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback code is nothing magical. It's simply a Javascript function that you pass as an argument to another function. You can therefore have a variable pointing to the callback function and call it on other events as well.

```
<script>
    $.fn.ready(function() {
        var src = $('#src').val();
        Meme('url1', 'canvas','','');

        var callbackFn = function() {
            Meme(src, 'canvas', $('#top-line').val(), $('#bottom-line').val());
            if(document.getElementById('stanley').checked) {
                src = 'url2';
                Meme(src, 'canvas', $('#top-line').val(), $('#bottom-line').val());
            } else if(document.getElementById('futurama').checked) {
                src = 'url3';
                Meme(src, 'canvas', $('#top-line').val(), $('#bottom-line').val());
            }
        });

        $('#top-line, #bottom-line').keyup(callbackFn);
        $('input[name="meme"]').change(callbackFn);
        $('#src').change(callbackFn);
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure if `$('#src').change` is the right event: you may want `keyup`, but the intent should be clear.

Comment: The image has stopped loading in canvas now.

Comment: You were right $('#src').change needs to be replaced with keyup. Its working fine now. However, I had to write separate function for each of these events to get it working.